# ServiceStack ORMLite paging on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ormlite-servicestack

I have an existing SQL Server 2008 database which has a number of views, stored procedures and functions.

I want to be able to `SELECT` data from one of these SQL functions and limit the number of rows that it returns in a paging scenario.

I have tried using `.Select` with `.Skip` and `.Take` as follows:

```cs
        public IEnumerable<Product> CallSqlFunction_dbo_Search_Products_View(int clientId,
            string environmentCode,
            int sessionId)
        {
            IEnumerable<Product> results;

            using (var db = _dbConnectionFactory.Open())
            {
                results = db.Select<Product>(@"
                    SELECT
                        * 
                    FROM 
                        [dbo].[Search_Products_View]
                        (
                            @pClientID, 
                            @pEnvironmentCode,
                            @pSessionId
                        )", new
                    {
                        pClientID = clientId,
                        pEnvironmentCode = environmentCode,
                        pSessionId = sessionId
                    })
                    .Skip(0)
                    .Take(1000);

                db.Close();
            }

            return results;
        }
```

This produces the following SQL which is executed on the SQL Server.

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'
                    SELECT
                        * 
                    FROM 
                        [dbo].[Search_Products_View]
                        (
                            @pClientID, 
                            @pEnvironmentCode,
                            @pSessionId
                        )',N'@pClientID int,@pEnvironmentCode varchar(8000),@pSessionId int',@pClientID=0,@pEnvironmentCode='LIVE',@pSessionId=12345
```

It means that this query returns 134,000 products, not the first page of 1000 I was expecting.  The paging happens on the API server once the SQL Server has returned 134,000 rows.

Is it possible to use ORMLite so that I can get it to generate the paging in the query similar to this:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT
    [t1].*
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[ProductId], [t0].[ProductName])
    FROM
        [dbo].[Search_Products_View](@pClientId, @pEnvironmentCode, @pSessionId) AS [t0]
    WHERE
        (LOWER([t0].[ProductStatus]) = @pProductStatus1) OR (LOWER([t0].[ProductStatus]) = @pProductStatus2) OR (LOWER([t0].[ProductStatus]) = @pProductStatus3)
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE 
    [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @pPageNumber + 1 AND @pPageNumber + @pNumberOfRowsPerPage
ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]',
N'@pClientId decimal(9,0),@pEnvironmentCode char(3),@pSessionId decimal(9,0),@pProductStatus1 varchar(8000),@pProductStatus2 varchar(8000),@pProductStatus3 varchar(8000),@pPageNumber int,@pNumberOfRowsPerPage int',
@pClientId=0,@pEnvironmentCode='LIVE',@pSessionId=12345,@pProductStatus1='1',@pProductStatus2='2',@pProductStatus3='3',@pPageNumber=0,@pNumberOfRowsPerPage=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

OrmLite will use the windowing function hack in <= SQL Server 2008 for its typed queries but not for Custom SQL. You'll need to include the entire SQL (inc. Windowing function) into your Custom SQL.

If you do this a lot I'd suggest wrapping the Windowing Function SQL Template in an extension method so you can easily make use of it in your custom queries, e.g:

```
results = db.Select<Product>(@"
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Search_Products_View]
        (
            @pClientID, 
            @pEnvironmentCode,
            @pSessionId
        )"
    .InWindowingPage(0,1000), new
    {
        pClientID = clientId,
        pEnvironmentCode = environmentCode,
        pSessionId = sessionId
    })
```

If you want to use DB Params for the offsets you'll need some coupling to use conventional param names:

```
results = db.Select<Product>(@"
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Search_Products_View]
        (
            @pClientID, 
            @pEnvironmentCode,
            @pSessionId
        )"
    .InWindowingPage(), new
    {
        pClientID = clientId,
        pEnvironmentCode = environmentCode,
        pSessionId = sessionId,
        pPageNumber = 0,
        pNumberOfRowsPerPage = 100
    })
```